# Bind to property of a control in another view

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have set up in a view the height of a control using dockpanels and alignments. 
I want to use the computed size of this control as an input for another control in another view.

MainWindow

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:View1 />
    <local:View2 />
</StackPanel>
```

View1

```
<DockPanel>
    ...
        <Button x:Name="myButton" />
    ...
</DockPanel>
```

View2 (where I want to bind the button's height to the first view)

```
<Button Height="{Binding Path=Button.Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:View1}}}" />
```

But it does not work...

I am looking if possible for a xaml-only solution with binding...

Comment: will you please provide more code and are you sure the AncestorType local is AnpotherView or AnotherView. Is it a typo ? or it actually exists in the code.

Comment: With "another view", you mean another window? How does it relate to the current window, are they both displayed at the same time, or is this a modal window, ...?

Comment: Gief explit type `AncestorType={x:Type local:AnpotherView}` ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ

Comment: Relplaced `AnotherView` by `AnotherViewOfMine` ...

Comment: Please post your full markup, including the view where the Control and the AnotherViewOfMine are created. You cannot use a RelativeSource binding unless AnotherViewOfMine  is actually a visual ancestor of the control.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using dependency properties in order to achieve this. Here is a sample based on your case:

View1:

```
<DockPanel>
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="Button in view1" FontSize="32"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

View1 codebehind. Notice that we handle loaded event in order to get the actual height of the button and to assign its value to the DependencyProperty we created:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ButtonHeight", typeof (double), typeof (View1), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

        public double ButtonHeight
        {
            get { return (double) GetValue(ButtonHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonHeightProperty, value); }
        }
        public View1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void View1_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonHeight = myButton.ActualHeight;
        }
```

Then in view2 we bind the button height to another dependency property in that user control:

And in view2 codebehind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ButtonHeight", typeof (double), typeof (View2), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

public double ButtonHeight
{
    get { return (double) GetValue(ButtonHeightProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ButtonHeightProperty, value); }
}

public View2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Finally the mainWindow xaml looks like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:View1 x:Name="View1"/>
    <local:View2 ButtonHeight="{Binding ElementName=View1,Path=ButtonHeight}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And the output:

[image]

Hope this helps